# Delphi: Hide Shortcut keys from Main Menu and Popup Menu

Tags: delphi, menu, vcl

how is it possible to hide the Shortcut keys which are displayed on the right of menu item captions in TMainMenu and TPopupMenu?

I want to preserve the shortkey activity when they are pressed, 
but I'd just like to have an option to switch from keys visible/invisible in the menus.

One way would be to add and remove them manually by editing the menu item captions on an event handler, but is there a better way?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Nope. Short of patching ShortCutToText at runtime. Even then the VCL would add the tab if there is a shortcut. See menus.TMenuItem.AppendTo for where the shortcut text is appended to caption.

Comment: Of course you can use OwnerDraw though.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz is it possible to hide the shortkeys using OwnerDraw?

Comment: Yes, what shows is whatever you draw. As far as the API is concerned they are just part of the menu string. You can even hide the mnemonics by stripping any possible ampersand, I think.